# Capturing Stored Procedure Parameters via Table Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, triggers

I have a table that has a Trigger associated with it for Update, Insert and Delete.  The Trigger works fine and executes.  Here is the code for my trigger:

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[trg_audit_TableName]
ON [dbo].viewLayers
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @inputbuffer table (EventType nvarchar(30),Parameters int,EventInfo nvarchar(4000))
insert into @inputbuffer exec('dbcc inputbuffer('+@@Spid+')')
declare @ins int
declare @del int
select @ins = count(*) from inserted
select @del = count(*) from deleted

insert into audit_TableName (eventtime, CurrentMachine, appName,  CurrentUser, eventtype, tsql)
select getdate(), host_name(), APP_NAME(), suser_sname(), 
    case 
        when isnull(@ins, 0) > 0 and isnull(@del, 0) > 0 then 'update' 
        when isnull(@ins, 0) > 0 and isnull(@del, 0) = 0 then 'insert' 
        else 'delete' 
    end, 
    EventInfo
from @inputbuffer
```

Now, if I run a stored procedure from the Management Studio, the TSWL data inserted into the table looks like this:

```
sp_TestInsert 'paramdata 1', 'paramdata 2'
```

But, if I run the procedure from my .NET appliation using an SQLCommand object, the TSQL field doesn't show the parameters:

```
sp_TestInsert;1
```

If I open up the profiler for this stored procedure when it is executed from .NET this is what I see:

```
exec sp_TestInsert @val1='paramdata 1',@val2='paramdata 2'
```

Yet, the audit table still shows

```
sp_TestInsert;1
```

*Is there a way that I can retrieve the parameters passed with the Stored Procedure?*

**EDIT:**
Depending on the stored procedure, it will insert / update / delete data in a table that has  the trigger

**EDIT 2:**
Here's a very brief example of the .NET Execution ('conn' is my SQLConnection object):

```
Using cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand 
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
     cmd.CommandText = "sp_TestInsert" 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", "paramdata 1")
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", "paramdata 2") 
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
 End Using
```

Comment: I'm curious, why is the purpose in knowing what the sp parameters were for your audit table? We generally only care about the old value vice the new value for auditing not the code that changed them. I can see where it might be nice to capture what proc was run, but are the parameters really that important?

Comment: That's a good point...  I guess I am just being overly particular. I can get the insert and delete data as it is, so that is probably good enough.

Comment: It's not really a matter of WHY we want to know the answer to this, or what the value would be for having it return the entire statement. I have a super audit system, and I get just what I need from just the proc name and the old/new field value, but I still want to know why it's so. So PLEASE if anyone has insight give a proper answer!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the trigger to also include the inserted / deleted data like so:

```
 declare @insData varchar(max)  
 set @insData = (select * from inserted for xml auto)  
 declare @delData varchar(max)  
 set @delData = (select * from deleted for xml auto)
```

And then inserted @insData and @delData into the audit table.  This now shows what was changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is executing the stored procedure with no parameters.  The semi-colon signifies the end of a statement in sql.

sp_TestInsert;1

I think this is what you are looking for

sp_TestInsert 1

This is assuming that "sp_TestInsert;1" is what you are passing from your code to sql server.

Comment: This is how the data is provided by the EventInfo.  If I open up the profiler for this stored procedure when it is executed from .NET this is what I see:

    exec sp_TestInsert @val1='paramdata 1',@val2='paramdata 2'

Yet, the audit table still shows
    sp_TestInsert;1

For the SQLCommand object, I set the CommandText to "sp_TestInsert" and then add Parameters (cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue).  Not sure if that matters.....

Comment: I know this is SOO old, but I'm running into that same issue and I want to know why DBCC INPUTBUFFER is not returning the SQL Statement that was run. I'm on SQL 2012 Enterprise. In any event, this answer is not correct